# LLVM compiler optimization bug or what?

Tags: c++, xcode, llvm, compiler-optimization

I stumbled inside a funny problem that I'm not able to understand.

Background is:

- LLVM 4.2 Compiler on XCode
- compiled with c++11 support
- compiled with `-Os`
- compiled for armv7/armv7s architecture

Now I realized there is a problem with some code that is present just when compiling with optimizations enabled.

The code is, verbatim:

```
static int foo(int tx, int sx, int w)
{
  int vs = 60;

  if (sx < vs*2 && tx > w - vs*2)
    return (sx + w - tx);
  else if (sx > w - vs*2 && tx < vs*2)
    return -(w - sx + tx);
  else
    return sx - tx;
}
```

Now, by going with LLDB I stepped code to track down a strange bug, and this lead me to realize that the first branch of the if is taken with input

```
sx = 648
tx = 649
w = 768
vs = 60
```

(these values are taken from directly from the locals table in XCode, I'm not able to query lldb about `vs` because I guess it gets optimized.)

The first branch is then `if (648 < 120 && ...` so there should be no way to take it but it actually happens. If I compile with -O0 then the bug just disappears.

An additional funny thing is the fact that for `sx = 647` and `tx = 648` the bug doesn't occur.

Now, things are two: or I'm missing something so obvious that 10 hours of debugging forbid me to see or there is a sort of bug in an optimization.

Any clues?

Some more background, this is the ASM generated:

```
    .private_extern __ZN5Utils12wrapDistanceEiii
    .globl  __ZN5Utils12wrapDistanceEiii
    .align  2
    .code   16                      @ @_ZN5Utils12wrapDistanceEiii
    .thumb_func __ZN5Utils12wrapDistanceEiii
__ZN5Utils12wrapDistanceEiii:
    .cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin9:
@ BB#0:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:tx <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:sx <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:w <- R2+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: vs <- 60+0
    sub.w   r3, r2, #120
    cmp r1, #119
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:tx <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:sx <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:w <- R2+0
    it  le
    cmple   r3, r0
Ltmp42:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:tx <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:sx <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:w <- R2+0
    ittt    lt
    sublt   r0, r1, r0
Ltmp43:
    addlt   r0, r2
    @DEBUG_VALUE: vs <- 60+0
    bxlt    lr
Ltmp44:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:tx <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:sx <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:w <- R2+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: vs <- 60+0
    cmp r3, r1
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:tx <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:sx <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:w <- R2+0
    it  lt
    cmplt   r0, #119
Ltmp45:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:tx <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:sx <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:w <- R2+0
    itttt   le
    suble   r1, r2, r1
Ltmp46:
    addle   r0, r1
Ltmp47:
    rsble   r0, r0, #0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: vs <- 60+0
    bxle    lr
Ltmp48:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:tx <- R0+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: wrapDistance:sx <- R1+0
    @DEBUG_VALUE: vs <- 60+0
    subs    r0, r1, r0
Ltmp49:
    @DEBUG_VALUE: vs <- 60+0
    bx  lr
Ltmp50:
Lfunc_end9:
    .cfi_endproc
```

If I place a print, eg `printf("%d < %d - %d",sx,vs*2,sx < vs*2)` before the if clause then the bug disappear.

This simple test case exibits the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 767; ++i)
{
  printf("test: %d, %d, %d",i,i+1,Utils::wrapDistance(i+1, i, 768))
}

...
test: 641, 642, -1
test: 642, 643, -1
test: 643, 644, -1
test: 644, 645, -1
test: 645, 646, -1
test: 646, 647, -1
test: 647, 648, -1
test: 648, 649, -769
test: 649, 650, -1
test: 650, 651, -1
test: 651, 652, -1
test: 652, 653, -1
test: 653, 654, -1
test: 654, 655, -1
...
```

**EDIT2**

I managed to reproduce the bug in a stand alone program, I just created an empty iOS project, then I defined the function twice, once in the AppDelegate.mm to be called directly from the same file and another one in a separate file:

**Test.h**

```
#ifndef TEST_H_
#define TEST_H_

class Utils
{
  public:
    static int wrapDistance(int tx, int sx, int w);
};

#endif
```

**Test.cpp**

```
#include "Test.h"

int Utils::wrapDistance(int tx, int sx, int w)
{
  int vs = 60;

  if (sx < vs*2 && tx > w - vs*2)
    return (sx + w - tx);
  else if (sx > w - vs*2 && tx < vs*2)
    return -(w - sx + tx);
  else
    return sx - tx;
}
```

**AppDelegate.mm**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#include "Test.h"

int wrapDistance(int tx, int sx, int w)
{
  int vs = 60;

  if (sx < vs*2 && tx > w - vs*2)
    return (sx + w - tx);
  else if (sx > w - vs*2 && tx < vs*2)
    return -(w - sx + tx);
  else
    return sx - tx;
}

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  ...

  for (int i = 0; i < 767; ++i)
  {
    NSLog(@"test inside: %d, %d, %d",i,i+1,wrapDistance(i+1, i, 768));
    NSLog(@"test outside: %d, %d, %d",i,i+1,Utils::wrapDistance(i+1, i, 768));
  }

    return YES;
}

...
```

**OUTPUT**

```
test inside: 644, 645, -1
test outside: 644, 645, -1
test inside: 645, 646, -1
test outside: 645, 646, -1
test inside: 646, 647, -1
test outside: 646, 647, -1
test inside: 647, 648, -1
test outside: 647, 648, -1
test inside: 648, 649, -1
test outside: 648, 649, -769
test inside: 649, 650, -1
test outside: 649, 650, -1
test inside: 650, 651, -1
test outside: 650, 651, -1
test inside: 651, 652, -1
test outside: 651, 652, -1
```

As you can see, the behavior for the function that is defined inside the file from which is called is correct, but the same thing doesn't apply for the other one, which shows the same bug. If I force not to inline the inner function with `__attribute__ ((noinline))` then both functions fail. I'm really groping into the dark.

Comment: It's highly likely that you're seeing undefined behaviour caused by an issue elsewhere in your code.  Can you construct a complete test-case?

Comment: This is the complete test case, the function doesn't rely on any external input, it's an static utility function used just to calculate distance between two tiles in a wrapped environment. The bug always occur with these input values. I should try to isolate it from the project or check ASM code I guess.

Comment: By "test-case", I mean an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), which would contain the driver code (i.e. the unit test or whatever required to exhibit the behaviour).  As I'm sure you're aware, many bugs have a habit of fixing themselves once the troublesome code is isolated from the rest of the the program ;)

Comment: Of course, it's possible (but very unlikely) that there really is a compiler bug.  But we'd need evidence of that (e.g. the corresponding ASM output)...

Comment: To take a guess re @OliCharlesworth's comment, if the optimizer placed the 120 in a constant table that was clobbered by a write to bad pointer location in some other code, it could explain all you are seeing.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I tried placing a test case out of context when the application starts and it exactly shows the problem. I feel in a dead-end because I can't understand how it is possible, probably I should just go to bed ;)

Comment: That ASM looks fine to me (although I don't have the ability to step through it live, etc.)  Is that definitely the -O3 output?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it should be -Os, assuming that the explicit option to show assembly is related to the current build option but I think so, I'll double check with -O0 just to be sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, your test-case implies that it's actually erroneously taking the `else if` branch.

But I take it back; there does seem to be a bug in the resulting ASM.<sup>*</sup>

Here is a formatted/annotated version of your ASM for the failing test:

```
% r0 = tx = 649
% r1 = sx = 648
% r2 = w  = 768

% w - vs*2
sub.w   r3, r2, #120         % r3 = 648

% if (sx < vs*2)
cmp r1, #119
it  le                       % (1) Not taken
  % if ((w - vs*2) < tx)
  cmple   r3, r0
ittt    lt                   % (2) Not taken
  % return (sx + w - tx)
  sublt   r0, r1, r0
  addlt   r0, r2
  bxlt    lr

% if ((w - vs*2) < sx)
cmp r3, r1
it  lt                       % (3) Not taken
  % if (tx < vs*2)
  cmplt   r0, #119
itttt   le                   % (4) Taken!  <<<<<<<<<<<<<
  % return -(w - sx + tx)
  suble   r1, r2, r1
  addle   r0, r1
  rsble   r0, r0, #0
  bxle    lr

% return sx - tx
subs    r0, r1, r0
bx  lr
```

Conditionals (3) and (4) are supposed to work together to achieve a logical-AND of the two sub-expressions.  In theory, block (4) is only executed if block (3) is executed **and** the subsequent comparison sets the appropriate status flags.<sup>**</sup>

However, this is implemented incorrectly.  Comparison (3) sets `Z`, which means that condition (3) is not triggered (it requires `N!=V`), so condition (4) is not executed.  Fine so far.  But it **is** sufficient to trigger condition (4) (it requires `(Z==1) || (N!=V)`), resulting in the problem you see.

To summarise, there are four possibilities here:

1. There really is a bug in the LLVM backend targeting ARM7.
2. The C code you provided isn't really the code you're compiling.
3. You have some invalid C code elsewhere that's triggering undefined behaviour, resulting in nonsense ASM being generated as a side-effect.
4. My analysis above is incorrect!

---

<sub>* Although it's 12:40am right now, so I may be mistaken...</sub>

<sub>** http://blogs.arm.com/software-enablement/206-condition-codes-1-condition-flags-and-codes/</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your analysis, never worked with arm asm directly so I would have required much more time to see the instructions and the general architecture used in branching. Now I always tend to exclude compiler errors, because 99.9999% of the times is a developer fault but I'd exclude hypothesis 2 and 4. So it is possible that some invalid code triggers undefined behaviour but I don't see how this could generate wrong binary? Otherwise that's really a bug.

Comment: @Jack: The compiler is allowed to assume that your code is valid, and to make optimisations accordingly.  If your code is somehow invalid, these optimisations may no longer make sense (hence undefined behaviour).  I'd say it's pretty unlikely that such a problem could manifest in a standalone function like this, though.  (However, I also thought it was pretty unlikely that there could be a compiler bug...)

Comment: I've been able to reproduce the bug in an empty project. All I needed to do is to place the function in a separated file and call it from the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` of app delegate. The weird thing: if I keep the function in the same file of the delegate then the bug doesn't occur. If I move it on its own file then it occurs. Check my edit.

Comment: The only way I found to fix the error is to provide a different implementation of the algorithm that produces equivalent result with different code. That fixed the optimization bug. In any case I made a report to Apple for that strange behavior. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ok, I submitted a bug report and they actually accepted and fixed it so it really was a bug. You know, 99.99% of the times it's developer fault but not this time.

Comment: @Jack: Awesome!  Out of interest, is there a link to the bug report I could peruse?